# Setting position re Monitor Settings (Lubuntu 20.04.4 LTS)

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop monitor and a primary 16:9 external VGA monitor, sitting to the left of the laptop.

I need to reverse the default settings to make mouse transitions sensible and smooth across the monitors (i.e. left to right, right to left, in one easy movement).

It's possible to do this but awkward. Getting the reversed monitors lined up correctly with the mouse is mildly annoying as the snap doesn't always work quite right.

Is there some way - perhaps a code for the terminal - that will simply reverse the default monitor positions and keep them lined up right? (In Windows 10, for instance, I can choose "Built in Monitor and External Display" or "External Display and Built in Monitor") and that's it. No fuss, no muss.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You can do the exact same setting in Ubuntu (settings > screens) by moving screens around. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Lubuntu uses LXQt; where the screen positions are set via Monitor Preferences (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.10/monitor_settings.html in the manual).  Do note these settings only take place after login (ie. won't impact `sddm` as it runs before LXQt has started).  There is no `sddm` GUI editor currently.  FYI:  There are some bugs in Qt 5.12.8 used by 20.04 that can *impair* performance of screen changes.. those were fixed in later Qt versions so don't exist on Lubuntu 20.10 & later, but as not security related were not back-ported to the LTS Qt version used by 20.04

Comment: ChanganAuto - As I say, "Getting the reversed monitors lined up correctly with the mouse is mildly annoying as the snap doesn't always work quite right." By that I mean, sometimes the snap doesn't snap correctly, so the monitor's image isn't fitting correctly on the screen. It IS possible, yes. But it's not quick and easy. Bodhi Linux, if I remember right, has a simple dropdown menu, not unlike Windows 10. So if Bodhi can do it, I figured Lubuntu could too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup. But I often switch between 3 workplaces.
I used arandr (screen layout editor) to configure the layouts and when I saved the configuration, it was just a script running xrandr

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1366x768 --pos 4480x672 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output HDMI-1 --off --output DP-2 --off --output HDMI-2 --off --output DP-2-1 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal --output DP-2-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x360 --rotate normal --output DP-2-3 --off
```

so I have these scripts with +x rights and run them whenever I switch workplace.
The default layout which the system assumes is not the way I want, but it is annoying. I would love if it just places the monitors in the right order automatically.

Comment: I find arandr to be vastly superior when it comes to snapping the screens in position. And you can save it. Good suggestion!